# Gray matpotlib figure face color turns black when saving the figure as .eps

Tags: matplotlib, eps

I am using the following code to get this:

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MWVu.png)

However, when saved as .eps, the face color of the figure turns from gray ( what I want) to black. See this:

[image][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cR35I.png)

Any reason why?

```
dim = np.arange(1, 32, 1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(7,9))
heatmap = ax.imshow(h.T, cmap=plt.cm.get_cmap('Blues', 4), clim=[1,144])
cbaxes = fig.add_axes([.8, .35, .04, .3])
cbar = fig.colorbar(heatmap, ticks = [1, 36, 72, 108, 144], label =  'Number of valid records per day', cax = cbaxes)
ax.set_ylabel("Days", fontsize=15)
ax.set_xlabel("Months", fontsize=15)
ax.set_title("Number of valid records per day", fontsize=20)
ax.set_yticks(range(0,31))
ax.set_yticklabels(dim, ha='center', minor=False, fontsize=12)
ax.set_xticks(range(0,13,1))
ax.set_xticklabels(ylabel[7:20], rotation = 45, ha = 'right')

ax.set_facecolor('gray')
cbar.set_label('Number of valid records')
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.5))

ax.tick_params(axis='y', which='major', pad=10)
ax.grid(which = 'minor', color = 'w')

fig.show()
plt.savefig("drive/My Drive/fig.eps")
```

Comment: This does not have a complete [mre]. Provide data with [How to provide a reproducible copy of your DataFrame using `df.head(30).to_clipboard(sep=',')`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52413246/7758804), then **[edit] your question**, and paste the clipboard into a code block.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably caused by your 'gray' colour actually being black with transparency (which is the **a** channel in rgb**a**), i.e. the rgba color (0,0,0,.5), which is black with a 50% transparency. If you ran your code interactively, you should have gotten a message:

> "The PostScript backend does not support transparency; partially
> transparent artists will be rendered opaque."

`.eps` (Postscript in the message refers to **e**ncapsulated **p**ost**s**cript) doesn't support transparency, I imagine under the hood when your figure is being saved as `.eps` it simply takes the color channels i.e. the rgb values, which is equivalent to setting alpha to 1.

You can either:

1. Rasterize your figure/axes before saving as `.eps` using `fig.set_rasterized(True)`/`ax.set_rasterized(True)`,
2. Save in a different format which supports transparency (`.pdf`, `.png` etc.)
3. Choose a color/cmap(colormap) which does not include transparency.

To expand #3 for your specific option, if it's the case that missing values aren't plotted and we're seeing the axes facecolor, you can try explicitly specifying an rgb color `ax.set_facecolor(.5,.5,.5)` instead of `ax.set_facecolor('grey')`.

Comment: “gray” in matplotlib is .5, .5, .5.